# Unit Test In Spring Boot, the object value changes after set?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have just started writing tests for my Spring Boot Project.

```
@Test
public void updatePassword_SetNewPasswordForQuizUser() throws QuizUserNotFoundException {
    QuizUser oldQuizUser = this.quizUserService.getQuizUserId("SmitShah");
    System.out.println(oldQuizUser);
    QuizUser updated = new QuizUser("SmitShah", "SmitPassword2", 
            true, false, false, 
            "");
    QuizUser updatedQuizUser = this.quizUserService.updateQuizUser(updated);
    System.out.println(updatedQuizUser);
    assertThat(updatedQuizUser.getPassword()).isNotEqualTo(oldQuizUser.getPassword());
}
```

The `oldQuizUser` within my test contains:

```
new QuizUser("SmitShah", "SmitPassword", true, false, false, "");
```

The output of `oldQuizUser` contains:

```
QuizUser{QuizUserId='SmitShah', Password='SmitPassword', IsAdmin=true, IsActive=false, IsOnline=false, Avatar='', createDateTime=null}
```

After calling the `updateQuizUser()` method, the output of `updatedQuizUser` contains:

```
QuizUser{QuizUserId='SmitShah', Password='$2a$10$fuVy.orndbmsgRQJptH5Se9iTTTI9EBhakwMFgmFrPqVdtcKCIPHq', IsAdmin=true, IsActive=false, IsOnline=false, Avatar='', createDateTime=null}
```

As you can see, the `oldQuizUser` contains a plaintext password, while `updatedQuizUser` contains a hashed password.

However, the assertion at the end of my test fails. After debugging, it seems that after running `updateQuizUser()`, the value of `oldQuizUser` is changed to the updated one.

Why is this happening?

These are the relevant parts from `QuizUserService` that are being invoked within the test:

```
@Override
public QuizUser updateQuizUser(QuizUser user) throws QuizUserNotFoundException {
    if(this.quizUserRespository.findById(user.getQuizUserId()).isPresent()) {
        QuizUser oldUser = this.quizUserRespository.findById(user.getQuizUserId()).get();
        if (user.getAvatar() != null) oldUser.setAvatar(user.getAvatar());
        if (user.getPassword() != null) oldUser.setPassword(pe.encode(user.getPassword()));
        if (user.isAdmin()) oldUser.setAdmin(user.isAdmin());
        this.quizUserRespository.save(oldUser);
        return oldUser;
    }
    else{
        throw new QuizUserNotFoundException();
    }
}


@Override
public QuizUser getQuizUserId(String id) throws QuizUserNotFoundException {
    if(this.quizUserRespository.findById(id).isPresent()){
        return this.quizUserRespository.findById(id).get();
    }
    else{
        throw new QuizUserNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the methods for quizUserService.getQuizUserId and quizUserService.updateQuizUser ? Cause it looks like they have the same reference.

Comment: @Brother added. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the result for: System.out.println(oldQuizUser); ? You posted the creating, not the println of the object, the old

Comment: Added too. @Brother

Comment: Can you print the oldQuizUser after the update? If looks the same as the updatedQuizUser,  could it be because they are in the same transaction and the JPA updated the reference.

Comment: @Brother yes, both of them are same after the update call.

Comment: Is there a way to remove that problem? or alternative to test this case?

Comment: I added an alternative test, holding the previous password in a string variable and then checking after

Comment: I'm confused why this is a problem in the first place?

Comment: @RobOhRob I think I did not understand the concept of Persistence (part of JPA).  And `Brother` correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the objects are the same in the persistence context, when you update it, the reference is also updated.

An alternative to test it, would be:

```
    @Test
    public void updatePassword_SetNewPasswordForQuizUser() throws QuizUserNotFoundException {
        QuizUser oldQuizUser = this.quizUserService.getQuizUserId("SmitShah");
        String oldPassword = oldQuizUser.getPassword();
        QuizUser updated = new QuizUser("SmitShah", "SmitPassword2", 
                true, false, false, 
                "");
        QuizUser updatedQuizUser = this.quizUserService.updateQuizUser(updated);
        assertThat(updatedQuizUser.getPassword()).isNotEqualTo(oldPassword);
    }
```